# Is it possible to print 16 times in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm making an application. As an example, I tried to print the letter 'a' 16 times in the following code. But it didn't work. This is because I do use 'return'. I know that. But it does not use error. How do I print the letter 'a' 16 times?

```
import React from "react";
import Game from "./game";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Game = new Game();
    console.log(this.Game.play());
  }
  draw = () => {
    for (let a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
      for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        return <div>a</div>;
      }
    }
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.draw();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>2048 Game With React</h2>
        <p>{this.draw()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The first `return` aborts the entire loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just us an array. Populate the array and then return it and React will render the array of components.

```
import React from "react";
import Game from "./game";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Game = new Game();
    console.log(this.Game.play());
  }
  draw = () => {
    let result = [];
    for (let a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
      for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        result.push(<div>a</div>);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.draw();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>2048 Game With React</h2>
        <p>{this.draw()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `return` aborts the entire loop so that you only get one `<div>`. You need to build up all of the `<div>`s and return either an array of `<div>` elements or a single `<div>` element with the 16 `<div>`s nested inside.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `fill` method from Array prototype, so you could do this in your render method

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>2048 Game With React</h2>
        <p>{Array(16).fill("a").map((letter, index) => <div key={index}>{letter}</div>)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to explicitly call a draw method, because the render method would take that roll. This method gets called automatically when the props object changes. So you would not need to call it with `componentDidMount` you can just leave it inside of the render method as you have it, since `this.draw()` will be called every time `render()` is called automatically.

Getting to your core question: your `this.draw` method would always return `<div>a</div>` because you are putting the return statement inside of your double for loop and therefore would always return when it hits that line (and will not keep looping).

As a start, you would want to make an array of components, instead of trying to return one component:

```
draw = () => {
  let output = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
    for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
      output.push(<div>a</div>);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

Since you seem to be making a game, this would not quite work the way you might want. I imagine you are trying to make a grid since you are using 2 for loops. You would need to either define this in a table, or use components that support a grid format.

So to answer your main question, if you are trying to print out 'a' 16 times, you would want to revise to something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Game from "./game";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Game = new Game();
    console.log(this.Game.play());
  }

  draw = () => {
    let output = [];
    for (let a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
      for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        output.push(<div>a</div>);
      }
    }
    return output;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>2048 Game With React</h2>
        <p>{this.draw()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because when you hit the first return in your for-statement, it will return it and skip the rest.

To work, you will have to return an array of jsx elements. Something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    b: ['b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b']
    }
  }
  draw () {
    return this.state.b.map(elm=>{
        return <div>{elm}</div>;
    });

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>2048 Game With React</h2>
        <div>{this.draw()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this !

```
draw = () => {
html = '';
for (let a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
    html +='<div>'+a+'</div>';
  }
}
return html;
};
```

Comment: *Try this* is not an answer. Write what you have done and why.

Comment: Also, this is a React question and you're suggesting HTML strings instead of JSX, which is bad practice.